# Resizing a hidden-frame

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to load a webpage into a hidden-frame (sdk/frame/hidden-frame) and then render a screenshot of it. I can get the screenshot just fine, but the frame is not properly sized. The screenshot is rendered by using the following code

```
var hiddenFrames = require("sdk/frame/hidden-frame");
let hiddenFrame = hiddenFrames.add(hiddenFrames.HiddenFrame({
    onReady: function() {
        this.element.contentWindow.location = "http://example.com";
        let self = this;
        this.element.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var cnvs = self.element.contentDocument.createElement("canvas");
            var width = self.element.contentDocument.body.clientHeight; //for some reason clientWidth is 0 for www.example.com
            var height = self.element.contentDocument.body.clientHeight;
            cnvs.width = width;
            cnvs.height = height;
            var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
            console.log(width+" "+height);
            ctx.drawWindow(self.element.contentWindow, 0, 0, width, height, "rgb(255,255,255)");
            console.log(cnvs.toDataURL());
        }, true, true);
    }
}));
```

I have tried changing the width and height of the iframe with

```
this.element.width = "1600";
this.element.height = "900";
```

changing the size of `element.contentWindow` with `resizeTo()`, and changing the size of the body. None of them seem to have an impact on the final screenshot, which looks like

[image]

Comment: if iframe is hidden why you want to resize it.

Comment: So the screenshot renders properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this on the parent page after including the iframe (or script that includes the iframe).

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
    $(this).css({
       width: 1600,
       height:  900
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. Firefox's XUL iframe object is different from the normal iframe object

Comment: theres no jquery available, this is firefox addon